# Does Stack Overflow use an automated tag corrector

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, migration

Does Stack Overflow use an automatic tagger for questions not tagged appropriately? Or does it wait for a user to report it?

I am aware of some research on tag-prediction, for both general social-networks ([Heymann, et al.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1390425)), and Stack Overflow ([Stanley, et al.](http://iccm-conference.org/2013-proceedings/papers/0077/index.html)), but am curious whether the present system uses any.

Comment: *"an automatic tagger for questions not tagged appropriately"* How would we know this?

Comment: I apologize for the late reply/accept. We are a group of researchers working on the Stack Overflow (SO) dataset for automatic tag prediction. We were curious whether SO uses any such tool (and if it does, what's the performance). And I tagged it with [meta-tag:bug] since I was new to SO then. Now I know better, since we have read the whole section on [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) :).

Comment: Tagging, tag corrections and retagging are all community efforts. There are, to the best of my knowledge, no automatic tools for it.

Comment: I would kill for automatic tag correction.  *Kill*.  Tags, that is.  Kill *tags*.  Not people.  No, not people.  Not normal people.  Maybe only ones that have no tagging skill.  Maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no automatic way to tell that a question is incorrectly tagged. That would require better natural language analysis than currently exists.

We rely on the community to fix these.

If you have a bug to report, tag the question on Meta with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: He was hoping the automatic bug triager would fix it. It did, of course: other community members. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray - The system works!

Comment: I apologize for the late reply/accept. We are a group of researchers working on the Stack Overflow (SO) dataset for automatic tag prediction. We were curious whether SO uses any such tool (and if it does, what's the performance). And I tagged it with [tag:bug] since I was new to SO then. Now I know better, since we have read the whole section on [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) :).

Comment: @govindjsk - Why not ask a question here on Meta - we do have a tag predictor, but I am not the right person to talk about it.

Comment: @Oded: FYI, I myself am the asker! Sorry for a changed display-name.